# CSS : Maintaining fixed height for DIV in Firefox and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, html

I have a master div and inside that i am showing multiple divs as a list.My HTML as below

```
<div id='divMasterContainer' style="height:200px;">
  <div id='child1'>
       // Some child contents here (Radio button / Button etc.. )
  </div>
  <div id='child2'>
    // Some child contents here (Radio button / Button etc.. )
  </div>
  <div id='child3'>
    // Some child contents here (Radio button / Button etc.. )
  </div>
</div>
```

So when rendering in firefox, ,The mastercontainer div is of height 200 px .But in IE , Its growing as of the number of child divs it holds.  I am using these div's  with jFlow plugin to implement a slider control.  I want to mainitain the same height for the master div in both the browsers. and i dont need a scrollbar in the master div too.

Comment: try using overflow:hidden for your mastercontainer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the master div has an overflow of 'hidden':

```
<div id='divMasterContainer' style="height:200px;overflow:hidden;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try having this in the style tag:

```
overflow:hidden;
```